# how to add emoticon in RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add emoticons(smileys) into WPF richtext box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674733/how-to-add-emoticonssmileys-into-wpf-richtext-box)

Now,I want to know , how to add emoticon in RichTextBox in WPF.
For example: when I type hi :)   , it will return as image(smile image) in RichTexBox.
I hope , you will help me. if anyone know the solution or example code

Thanks

Comment: same question has been posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674733/how-to-add-emoticonssmileys-into-wpf-richtext-box

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a prebuilt solution for this, but, as you're using WPF, you can either react to change of the text inside the RichTextBox via the TextChanged event or via your PropertyChanged -if it's MVVM-.

Once you know text changed you give it a pass by using a simple search (there are way better ways to do this parsing, but for the sake of a simple example just use a simple string search). If you find the text you want, I mean, the token corresponding your smiley `hi :)` then you can insert the image on that position by playing with the FlowDocument inside the RichTextBox

**Before parsing**

```
 <RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
     <Paragraph>
      <Run>Hello :) world!</Run>
     </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
 </RichTextBox>
```

**After parsing**

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
     <Paragraph>
      <Span>
         <Run Text="Hello"/>
         <Image Width="16" Source="Your emoticon source"/>
         <Run Text=" world"/>
       </Span>
     </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
 </RichTextBox>
```

That should give you an idea of how to begin.

Comment: your solution is the best for me.if i want to use behind code in C#, how can I?

Comment: Then generate a delegate within your XAML for the TextChanged event and make the changes on that method, then, set the RichTextBox content via the property (remember you'll not have something like .Text property but the FlowDocument which is, indeed, the one you need).

Comment: I'm beginner WPF,I'm not clear. Can you show me some example.

Comment: I will suggest you to start reading about Flow Documents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx Then try out something, remember SO is about specific questions but not guidance as general :) start trying something and then go asking step by step for specific topics on which you need help

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599014/WPF-RichTextBox-supporting-smileys